# Is there a Cocoa type for representing a 3D point

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In [Cocoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29) there is a [NSPoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html) type to represent points in 2d-space. I can't find a way to represent a 3D type. Is there one and in that case what is it called? Or should I roll my own?

Comment: @vids There is no such thing.  Simply make your own objective-C class.  it's that simple.

Comment: A *class* for a simple structure of three of the same type of primitive with no methods/functions? How about a *struct*? Objective-C does not invalidate (or even complicate) the use of the rest of C. Given NSPoint is also a struct (because it *does not need to be anything else*), I don't see the need to make it a full-on class.

Comment: More relevant to a 3D point, you typically have a lot of them, need to perform computation on all of them quickly, and you do things with their data rather than asking them to do things themselves. Accessing their x/y/z members shouldn't need to go through ObjC messaging overhead vs. myPoint.z. This very loudly cries for a *struct*.

Comment: it's for a framework. A client application may use it *both* for displaying it using eg opengl and also for using it in computations. That is - similar use-case as for the `NSPoint` type.

Comment: oh, and there is really not "a lot of stuff". Typically just a few points in there so performance issues to bother about I recon.

Comment: @Joe: I'm speaking to you with the same respect you're giving others. "Your question is rather silly..." and so on is hardly constructive. If you want others to speak to you with a certain level of respect, try *approaching* them with at least that level of respect yourself. You set the tone yourself, don't blame others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right, make your own. I use something like this:

```
typedef struct Point3D_ {
  CGFloat x, y, z;
} Point3D;
```

Comment: @Joe Blow, can you elaborate on which situations?

Comment: Might also be of value to others to post a quick category method on NSValue, to provide equivalent functionality to valueWithPoint: and pointValue but for the Point3D_ type?

Comment: @Joe Blow: a typo I think; did you mean always use an objective-c object?

Comment: @Joe Blow, why the hate about struct? What's so much better about classes for such simple types?

Comment: @Joe Blow Classes bring polymorphism, inheritance and encapsulation. I wouldn't have a 3D point extend any other kind of class (no need for polymorphism) and I wouldn't let any other class derive from it (no need for inheritance), and I don't see what kind of hidden data it needs to deal with (no need for encapsulation). That said, you can make functions that deal with 3D points just as easily as you can make methods for a class. What am I missing here? What justifies the cost of using the Objective-C runtime when you can get the same useful benefits without it?

Comment: @Joe Blow No, therefore, please enlighten me. Under which circumstances have you used polymorphism, inheritance or encapsulation for 3D points?

Comment: @Joe Blow: You're saying a lot but really not offering hard facts to support your claims. Structs are still valid, useful things (they're found ALL OVER the place in modern Cocoa). If you can't back up your claims you're just flapping your jaw. "I can assure you from vast experience" is not helpful and is more than a little condescending without explanation.

Comment: @Joe Blow I'm doing pretty well, thank you. How are you? The original question was, "have you ever used polymorphism, inheritance or encapsulation for 3D points?" Besides, I think you're confusing vertices and points. The geometric concept of a "3D point", akin to a geometric 2D point like a CGPoint, has no color, texture, associated quad, surface or normal in itself. A vertex is a point with a bucket of attributes such as those you named. The complexity of the data might help justify a class for vertices, but on pure XYZ components? No thanks.

Comment: @Joe Blow: The difference may be negligible for iterating and accessing the members of a handful of points but the performance difference *is* there and adds up. Even with your "inevitable stuff" if it's still a collection of values that needs to be accessible *quickly*, arguing to add ObjC messaging overhead is asinine.

Comment: @Joe Blow Besides, ObjC classes to represent vertices must have made it much harder to use vertex buffers to get better 3D performances.

Comment: @Joe Blow, @zneak wow, this question really caught fire. :) I ended up going with a struct with the only rationale beeing that how `NSPoint` is done - Recognition is always to prefer adhering to the Principle of Least Astonishment. I completely agree with using a class here since lots of operations are associated with the type. I guess if the cocoa-guys could redo cocoa perhaps they would go for a class too?

Comment: @vidstige, it sure brought up fiery passions. Though, for operations that don't require polymorphism, there aren't a lot of differences between making a class and methods and making a struct and functions.

Comment: @vidstige: No, they wouldn't. They didn't for iOS and they won't be any time soon. A point - 2D or 3D - is just that: a point. It needs nothing else, wants nothing else, and therefore makes no sense to add the messaging overhead of Obj-C. Good engineering is avoiding *overengineering*. A point is just a point.

Answer (score 4):

While I have yet to remember or find something in the core of AppKit or Cocoa that's directly analagous to CGPoint, Apple do provide some types within "extra" frameworks. Here's a collection of what I've got so far.

### SceneKit

Apple's SceneKit provides a type `SCNVector3`, which is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_DataTypes/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SCNVector3) to be a simple struct:

```
typedef struct SCNVector3 { CGFloat x, y, z; } SCNVector3;
```

There are [a few helper functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_Functions/) like `SCNVector3Make` and 
`SCNVector3EqualToVector3` and one to convert between GLKit vectors.

### GLKit

Apple's GLKit provides a type [GLKVector3](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKVector3/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/GLKVector3), with even more features and helper functions.

```
union _GLKVector3 {
    struct { float x, y, z; };
    struct { float r, g, b; };
    struct { float s, t, p; };
    float v[3];
};
typedef union _GLKVector3 GLKVector3;
```

As you can see, it is a union of a number of types, including a simple x/y/z struct and an indexable array of floats — so once you create one you can conveniently access its value in many different ways as makes sense in your context(s).

Besides a simple `GLKVector3Make`, there's a number of geometric calculation helpers, e.g. `GLKVector3Length` and `GLKVector3DotProduct` and and `GLKVector3Lerp`.

This one seems like a nice one to use if you don't mind pulling in GLKit.

### SpriteKit

Apple's SpriteKit defines a `vector_float3`, which is [a bit messier](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/vector_float3):

```
typedef __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3))) float vector_float3;
```

This uses a [compiler extension](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#vectors-and-extended-vectors) (Clang and perhaps GCC too?) to define this as a SIMD-friendly type. But it doesn't seem to be particularly developer-friendly other than that.

### CoreLocation

I'm guessing this isn't a good choice in most cases, but Apple's CoreLocation provides a specialized multidimensional type for locations. [CLLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/initWithCoordinate:altitude:horizontalAccuracy:verticalAccuracy:timestamp:) has properties for latitude/longitude/altitude (in addition to a timestamp, accuracy values, speed, course, etc.) So you could use this for 3D data, but only recommended if your data's relative to the earth's surface!

Comment: Great answer. There is a minor typo: Under CoreLocation, line 3, "timesetamps" -> timestamp. The correction is only one character, so I can't edit it.

Comment: @ZhigangAn Thanks for the tip, I fixed it. (Don't you wish they'd get rid of that character limit thing…!)

Comment: I wish so. But it is intended to block scam editing. I can understand and bear that. [sad face]

Answer (score 3):

Also do this to make creation of Point3D easier:

```
Point3D Point3DMake( CGFloat xx, CGFloat yy, CGFloat zz ){
  Point3D p;  
  p.x = xx; p.y = yy; p.z = zz;
  return p;
}
```

Comment: Why? This is something for which you need to give *real* and *measurable* reasons, not sweeping statements.

Comment: I have the exact same 'make' function, because it replicates the NSMakePoint() function from the Foundation framework. I guess you might want a class if you want to hide lots of 3d-point functions and behaviour, but I mostly use the Point3D typedef inside a class that actually uses it, Point3D is just a simple primitive type.

Comment: For the record, my comment above was aimed at Joe, not quaertym. :-)